# Invoke SharePoint Web Service With Axis2 client authenticate

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, authentication, apache-axis

I'm trying to run the following in the main of my java class.  The code uses the stub to first authenticate and then bring back the collection of lists in a microsoft sharepoint site.

The code is as follows:

```
    ListsStub stub = new ListsStub();

        HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpT

ransportProperties.Authenticator();

                auth.setUsername(username);
                auth.setPassword(pw);
                auth.setDomain(domain);
                auth.setHost(host);

                List schemes = new ArrayList(1);
                schemes.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
                 auth.setAuthSchemes (schemes);


                stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(
                org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE,
                auth);
                stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty (HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
                        HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
                //stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty (HTTPConstants.PROXY, proxy);


                String liste = "sharepointlist";
                String document2ID;

                    ListsStub.GetListCollection req = new ListsStub.GetListCollection();

                    ListsStub.GetListCollectionResponse res = null;
                    try {
                        res = stub.getListCollection(req);
                    } catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

I get a 401 that indicates my login is incorrect:

org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:310)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:200)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:76)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:400)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:402)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis2.axis2userguide.ListsStub.getListCollection(ListsStub.java:1936)
    at gov.nasa.jpl.spconnect.MainKickOff.main(MainKickOff.java:73)

Does anyone know why I might be getting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you solved that but... for now I think Authenticator is deprecated with a new abstract class but I passed this error by this way

```
your_stub_object._setProperty(Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "loginname");
your_stub_object._setProperty(Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "loginsecret");
```

You must obtain your stub object from the object you use when you have a call

```
javax.xml.rpc.Stub your_stub_object=((javax.xml.rpc.Stub)(sp.getService1Soap()));
```

sp is myServiceSoapProxy file.

I authenticated .NET webservices by this way. .NET Service which I coded is basic authenticated. If you got 401 this mean login failure, if you got somewhere 403 its ssl related.

I hope this helps folks.